# Error installing in Net::SSLeay

Tags: perl, cpan

Here is the stdout for installation:

```
CPAN Terminal>  i Net::SSLeay

Installing Net::SSLeay (1.58)
Running [/usr/bin/perl /usr/bin/cpanp-run-perl /home/greymonkey/.cpanplus/5.14.2/build/Net-SSLeay-1.58/Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site]...
*** Found OpenSSL-1.0.1e installed in /usr
*** Be sure to use the same compiler and options to compile your OpenSSL, perl,
    and Net::SSLeay. Mixing and matching compilers is not supported.
Do you want to run external tests?
These tests *will* *fail* if you do not have network connectivity. [n]
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Writing Makefile for Net::SSLeay
Writing MYMETA.yml
[ERROR] MAKE failed: No such file or directory cp lib/Net/SSLeay.pm blib/lib/Net/SSLeay.pm
AutoSplitting blib/lib/Net/SSLeay.pm (blib/lib/auto/Net/SSLeay)
blib/lib/Net/SSLeay.pm: some names are not unique when truncated to 8 characters:
cp lib/Net/SSLeay.pod blib/lib/Net/SSLeay.pod
cp lib/Net/SSLeay/Handle.pm blib/lib/Net/SSLeay/Handle.pm
/usr/bin/perl "-Iinc" /usr/share/perl/5.14/ExtUtils/xsubpp  -typemap /usr/share/perl/5.14/ExtUtils/typemap -typemap typemap  SSLeay.xs > SSLeay.xsc && mv SSLeay.xsc SSLeay.c
cc -c   -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -DDEBIAN -fstack-protector -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -O2 -g   -DVERSION=\"1.58\" -DXS_VERSION=\"1.58\" -fPIC "-I/usr/lib/perl/5.14/CORE"   SSLeay.c
SSLeay.xs:153:25: fatal error: openssl/err.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [SSLeay.o] Error 1


[ERROR] Unable to create a new distribution object for 'Net::SSLeay' -- cannot continue
```

It seems there's 'openssl/err.h' missing, help I'm new to perl. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Argh, headers for ssl library is missing. I apt-get the dev package and problem solved.

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

Comment: Is this the solution then?

Comment: Thank you! This does it for *ubuntu*!

Answer (score 16):

For Fedora/CentOS users:

```
yum install openssl-devel
```

edit: as others have said, the OpenSSL headers were missing. On Fedora/CentOS, these headers are provided by the `openssl-devel` package, which should therefore be installed.

Comment: While this may give an answer, can you please xpand on the answer and provide some commentary as to why it's failing and what's missing?

Answer (score 1):

For fedora users:

```
yum groupinstall 'Development Tools' 'Development Libraries'

yum install zlib-devel libyaml-devel openssl-devel gdbm-devel readline-devel ncurses-devel libffi-devel curl git openssh-server redis libxml2-devel libxslt-devel libcurl-devel libicu-devel python
```

Source: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/User:Axilleas/GitLab